Figures and tables are not shown
I was writing in a \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} and figures and tables were shown. When i shifted to \documentclass[]{IEEEphot} figures and tables are not shown anymore. I have included all the packages from the old template and tried to change image extension from .png to .eps and .pdf but nothing works.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide small example of your document which reproduce your problem. Dou you consider instruction for IEEEphot document class (https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/IEEE_Photonics_Journal_instructions2.pdf)?

Where we can find IEEEphot.cls?

Better not to include the image extension at all and let the code figure it out as that will be more reliable. But we will need to see a minimal example of the code you're using and know where to find the class to investigate the issue.
